# Deploying Angular Application to GitPages - Not Routing Properly

Tags: angularjs, angular, github, npm, github-pages

**Disclaimer:** I am not a frontend guy by trade. I am being asked to deploy an Angular application other engineers have created.

I have gone through the process of deploying an [Angular application to GitPages](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) and have also tried the handy [Angular CLI GH Pages library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-ghpages). However, they both have the same issue, and I'm not sure if it's the application itself or how I am deploying it.

The base page loads fine, but all other resources (image/font files, links to other pages, etc.) do not load properly. This is because they are not using the proper base URL; our corporate GitHub makes us use `https://....com/<org>/<repo>` as the URL. All resources outside of the base page are not prepending the `/<org>/<repo>/` part to the URL, so they are all returning 404s.

My `index.html` file in `docs/` contains the proper `base href="/<org>/<repo>/"` and the `docs/` folder contains all needed images and font files in its `assets/` subdirectory, so I'm not sure what gives. I have also copied `index.html` to `404.html`.

Am I missing something? Or is it possible that this web application was not created correctly for GH Pages?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change the base href to index.html only and all will work from there

`base href="index.html"`

From there it will take the path properly

Comment: Just tried that, unfortunately I obtained the exact same behavior.

Comment: add the github page path

Comment: @LowLevelSoCal angular has its won routing mechanism to point to the right view, but in order to run angular app, there should be one index.html page as per suggestion. can you share what is your dist folder content?